# Java Why is char = char^char different from char^= char?

Tags: java, xor

I was solving a problem in leet code and noticed the following code was not allowed in Java,

```
char c = 's';
c = c^c;
```

While the following was

```
char c = 's';
c^=c;
```

Is there a particular reason? Thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

This is also true for plus or minus. c^c is evaluated as an int so the right hand side is int and can not be assigned into a char.
In the ^= case, the right hand side is char, and can be applied onto a char.
This is not the most obvious behavior.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks! That actually sheds some light on compound assignment operators for me.